# How do I implement a tip jar in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, android-pay

I have created a Chrome extension that I would like to give away for free, but provide a "tip jar" on the extension's options page where people can, if they want, opt send me a small amount of money to show their appreciation. I've looked through the documentation for [one-time payments](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments) and [Google Wallet for Digital Goods](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/google_wallet), but nothing I see there seems like a fit. It seems like the only options listed are:

1. *Free extension, no payment mechanism:* Not desirable because I want to offer people the option to pay something.
2. *Paid extension:* No, I want it to be free.
3. *Free trial:* This will make people think that the extension is limited in some fashion unless they pay, which it isn't.
4. *In-app purchases:* Same as above. I'd rather that my extension not be marked as having in-app purchases, since there is no limitation that you have to pay to remove, and the only thing paying gets you is good karma.

Is there a built-in Chrome Web Store option that is suitable for what I'm trying to do? If not, can Google Wallet be leveraged in some way to provide "tip jar" functionality, or will I have to find some other payment mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of developers implement voluntary tips via [PayPal donation buttons](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside).

One could simply add the button to their options page. E.g.: [[1]](https://github.com/deanoemcke/thegreatsuspender/blob/master/options.html#L84-L91) [[2]](https://github.com/mikespook/BetterHackerNews-Chrome-Extension/blob/master/donate.html)

---

Cautionary tale: PayPal can, in principle, throw a hissy fit over collected funds, but as long as you don't rake in thousands you should be okay.

> Please note: Fundraisers that are not verified nonprofits will be asked to demonstrate how their donations will be used, once they raise more than $10,000

---

Patreon is currently gaining popularity. I know at least one extension (Enhanced Steam) that went that route.

Comment: I had considered PayPal, and the main hesitation I had was exactly what you mention: PayPal doesn't seem to be very keen on this usage. But it might be the only way to go. It's not like I expect to get anywhere near $10,000.

Comment: 1) It is indeed an extremely common usage of PayPal 2) PayPal is prone, in general, to very arbitrary actions, so YMMV no matter what you do